# vba - compare value in different cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have two cells in one sheet - lets call it DATA sheet.
and I have another sheet - lets call it SEARCH sheet.
I want to compare the two cells in DATA, with the info I have a SEARCH.

lets say, if: (cell A.value in DATA is in column X in SEARCH) and (cell B.value in DATA in column Y in SEARCH) - both in the same row in SEARCH - then give me the first value of this row in sheet SEARCH.

is it possible with VBA?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you looking for this..

```
Sub comp_value_in_diff_cells()
On Error Resume Next
lastrowA = Worksheets("DATA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrowB = Worksheets("DATA").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If lastrowA = lastrowB Then
    For i = 1 To lastrowA
        search1 = Worksheets("DATA").Range("A" & i).Value
        search2 = Worksheets("DATA").Range("B" & i).Value
        With Worksheets("SEARCH")
            For j = 1 To (.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count)
                a = .Range(j & ":" & j).Find(search1).Row
                avalue = .Range(j & ":" & j).Find(search1).Column
                b = .Range(j & ":" & j).Find(search2).Row
                bvalue = .Range(j & ":" & j).Find(search2).Column
                If a = b Then
                    If avalue < bvalue Then
                        If Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then
                            Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i).Value = Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i).Value & "|" & search1
                        Else
                            Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i).Value = search1
                        End If
                    Else
                        If Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then
                            Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i).Value = Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i).Value & "|" & search2
                        Else
                            Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i).Value = search2
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End With
    Next i
Else
    Msgbox ("DATA Sheet A & B Mismatch")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be aware that `.UsedRange.Rows.Count` is tricky in Excel 2016 (I don't remember how it works on previous versions)... Not always UsedRange starts form `Row=1`... It can be start - for example - form `Row=5`... then last row is not `Rows.Count` ! If I can advise - better approach is: `lastRow = (sheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Row + sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)`

Comment: @LukaszDev agreed completely. Edited as per advice

Comment: and if there are more then one match, and I want to copy all the right matches from the SEARCH sheet to the DATA sheet?

Comment: @danijinji, Please check the edited version. Kindly mark as solution if it works

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible :) You have 3 way:

**1. Loop (example For)**

```
Function FindPair(ByRef CellA As Range, ByRef CellB As Range) As Variant ' <- Change Variant for specific Type of data

    'Set default value if not found match
    Set FindPair = Nothing

    Dim sheetToSearch As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'Check input
    If CellA Is Nothing Or CellB Is Nothing Then
        Call MsgBox("Something is wrong!", vbExclamation)
        Exit Function
    Exit Function

    'For easy ro read
    Set sheetToSearch = Sheets("Search")

    lastRow = (sheetToSearch.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Row + sheetToSearch.UsedRange.Rows.Count) 'First row of UsedRange + rows count

    'Look up
    For r = 0 To lastRow

        'Change column here, if you need
        If sheetToSearch.Range("A" + r).Value = CellA.Value Then

            If sheetToSearch.Range("B" + r).Value = CellB.Value Then

                'Return data
                FindPair = sheetToSearch.Range("A" + r).Value
                Exit For

            End If
        End If
    Next r

    'You can compare *.Value = *.Value - for compare binary data
    'or *.Text = *.Text - for compare value like as text with formatting

End Function
```

**2. Find**

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Find()`

*Please look for documentation how it works: [VBA Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)*

**3. Vlookup**

`Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup()`

*Please look for documentation how it works: [Excel VLookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)*